# My KDE is using gdm, and I think it's causing errors

Tags: gnome, kde, desktop-environment, gdm

My system is debian 11 and recently I migrated from Gnome to KDE. I don't think I did a clean job migrating it, but all I did was installing KDE in `tasksel` and swapping the desktop environment.

My login screen still appears to be gnome, though when I login (by selecting desktop environment in the login screen) I can go by with KDE. But in `who` there are always two sessions:

```
Jackson     :1           Mar  8 11:06 (:1)
Jackson     pts/0        Mar  8 11:06 (:1)
```

which I don't understand. Perhaps because of the following?:

I heard that KDE uses `sddm` but there is no `sddm` in the `systemctl` but `gdm`, which is gnome display manager. If I kill `gdm` then my whole GUI shuts off. Also, every time I log out or shutdown, there are tons of errors from `/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session`. I think these all are from the same origin.

Why is this happening, and how do I 'correct' this?

Answer (score 0):

`gdm` is just a display manager, recommended for the Gnome desktop environment. KDE recommends `sddm` display manager for it, so I just changed the display manager to `sddm` and that solved the problem.

Comment: Nice :-) The answer would be improved if you added the steps you took to change the DM. Someone might find themselves in the same bind, find your solution but can't follow it as they don't know how to.